# How to show $k \cdot a + c \cdot b \ge \frac{1}{2} \cdot (k+c) \cdot (a+b)$?

Tags: inequality

Assume k, c, a, b $\gt$ 0 and that $k \ge c$ and $a \ge b$. Prove $k \cdot a$ + $c \cdot b$ $\ge$ $\frac{1}{2}\cdot (k+c) \cdot (a+b)$. This is what I have so far:

$2\cdot k\cdot a +2\cdot c \cdot b$ = $(k\cdot a + k\cdot a)$ + $(c\cdot b + c\cdot b)=(k\cdot a + c\cdot b)$ + $(k\cdot a + c\cdot b)\ge(k\cdot a + c\cdot b)$ + $(k\cdot b + c\cdot b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(k-c)(a-b) \geq 0$

$ka+bc \geq bk+ac$

$2(ka+bc) \geq bk+ac+ka+bc$

$2(ka+bc) \geq (a+b)(k+c)$

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @Leedle please consider upvoting the answer if it made sense (up arrow on the left side)

Comment: Also, you can accept it by clicking on the tick symbol (if it doesn't work straight away, wait ten minutes then click again) if you feel this is the most helpful answer. There can be only one accepted, so accept only the best one. I would advise waiting for a few hours so that you can consider the most helpful answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to upvote. But I will mark the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
 2(k a+c b)-(k+c)(a+b) 
= & 2 k a+2 c b-k a-c a-k b-b c \\
= & -k a+c b-c a-k b \\
= & (k-c) a+(c-k) b \\
= & (k-c)(a-b)\\ \geqslant & 0 \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore $$k  a + cb \ge \frac{1}{2} (k+c)(a+b)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $k≥c$ and $a≥b$. And we have to prove that $ka+bc≥(k+c)(a+b)/2$. Now by algebraic expansion we can write it out like these $$ka+bc≥(k+c)(a+b)/2$$ $$or, ka+bc≥kb+ac$$. Since $k≥c$ and $a≥b$ by Appling rearrangement inequality, the result follows.